# Rails 6 Docker with PostgreSQL Connection Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently starting with Docker and trying to adapt my first application with a Docker- and a Docker-compose file.

It seems to work fine, until I reach the point where I want to create my database. I set up the environment variables correctly and reflected them in my database.yml file

Here's my `.env`:

```
POSTGRES_USER='deploy'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='deploy'
POSTGRES_DB='nkbrf_db'
```

Here's my `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
        - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        env_file:
            - '.env'
        ports: 
        - "5432"
    web:
        build: .
        command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
        volumes:
            - .:/nkbrfqm
            - bundler_gems:/bundle
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            RAILS_ENV: development
        depends_on:
            - db
volumes:
    postgres:
    bundler_gems:
```

It sets up everything correctly but if I try to create my database with

> docker-compose run web rake db:create

I get the following error:

> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
> "root"

Where does this user "root" come from? Is something wrong with my environment variable settings?

Comment: A tip here is to use `<%= ENV.fetch('POSTGRES_USERNAME') %>` which raises an error if the key is not present. Try it and you will find that typo really fast.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I read it could have something to do with old volumes that were not deleted aswell, but I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: From the look of its its just that you are referencing `POSTGRES_USERNAME` but thats not what you are defining in .env. I also doubt you need to use .env as Docker provides a boatload of ENV vars for everything configuration related.

Comment: `ENV['POSTGRES_USER']` actually seems to be the ENV var set by the postgres image in the the container. If you want to use a different user then set it it up in the docker configuration. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove single-quote `'` in the `.env`  file then you need to remove all containers in the compose file(`docker-compose rm`). then execute `docker-compose up -d`

Example

`# .env`

```
POSTGRES_USER=deploy
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=deploy
POSTGRES_DB=nkbrf_db
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks mate, I fixed the typo in the env (dumb me) and removed the containers and it works! Thanks :)